# Laravel new error- Undefined variable:donor, method 'table' not found in \Illuminate\..\DB

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm able to get the the data for particular email after entering it. However this can only take place after getting into that page. But now, before I do that I need to enter the user to the database and send him an email. After entering the info and submitting it, I get an error that tells "undefined variable:donor". Nevertheless, the user still gets added into the database but I can't go to the next page and get an error because it also has a function together that sends an email(receipt.blade.php) which is giving the error because "donor" is undefined.

My controller has these:

```
use App\Donor;
use App\Video;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

The function is as

```
public function getUserReceipts(Request $data){
    $email = $data->email;

    $donor = Donor::where('email', $email)->get(); 

   return view('emails.receipt')->with(compact('donor'));
}
```

The receipt.blade.php page has the function suggested in one of the answers by sandeesh

```
@foreach($donor as $value)
    {{ $value->first_name }}
    {{ $value->last_name }}
    {{ $value->amount_donated }}
@endforeach
```

the function that sends the email is:

```
public function thankyoupage(Request $data, Mailer $mailer){
$donor = Donor::create([
            'first_name'=> $data->first_name,
            'last_name' => $data->last_name,
            'email' => $data->email,
            'video_count' => $video_count,
            'amount_donated' => $data->amount_donated,
});

$mailer
            ->to($data->input('email'))
            ->send(new \App\Mail\MyMail(($data->input('first_name')),($data->input('last_name')),
                ($data->input('amount_donated'))));

return redirect()->action('PagesController@thank1');
    }
```

My mail.php is as follows:

```
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $first_name, $last_name, $amount_donated;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($first_name,$last_name,$amount_donated)
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        $this->amount_donated = $amount_donated;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('myemailid12341@gmail.com')
            ->view('emails.receipt');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Donor class? Does it extend the Model class? Also in your second solution try replacing `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` with `use DB;`

Comment: Can you show us your Donor table structure and a sample data showing multiple rows with the same email? Because the database queries are working as intended and you should be getting back all the result with the same email unless you don't have any more rows for that particular email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` with `use DB;`

Here's your main problem. You return the view within the loop. This causes the view to be rendered for the first donor and the rest gets ignored. You need to pass the donors to the view and then loop in the view to display them. Do this.

Controller

```
public function getUserReceipts(Request $data)
{
    $email = $data->email;

    $donors = Donor::where('email', $email)->get();

    return view('emails.receipt')->with(compact('donors'));
}
```

In your view

```
@foreach($donors as $donor)
    {{ $donor->first_name }}
    {{ $donor->last_name }}
    {{ $donor->amount_donated }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks sandeesh,it works But, now i get the error saying "undefined variable: donors". It is adding the user to the database and everything is fine but I am also sending the email to the user which is the receipt.blade.php file. 
So, it gives error while trying to go to the next page from the code you provided--"@foreach($donors as $donor)", by saying donors is undefined in the receipt.blade.php. If thats the case, how do I define it?Because it is passed with compact as you have shown

Comment: You cannot use the same view with other controllers unless you inject it with the `$donors` collection. Laravel can't magically resolve a variable. You should plan your views and reuse them accordingly. Your question was help with this and i've done my part solving it. If you need assistance with another issue feel free to create one with the information needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've edited and added some stuff, could you please have a look at it.Let me know if you think I should create a separate question

Comment: @AJth please create a new question and this requires a different answer. I'm already preparing the answer. I'll post it in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Add at the top

```
use DB;
```

Or

```
$donor = Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table..
```

Either use the alias and import it or the full path.This might also happen because your aliases in config/app.php are out of whack.

Comment: I tried it,didn't work. Probably due to the problem sandeesh has mentioned. His suggestion helped but, not fully,and I still have a problem. Could you kindly have a look at my question which I have edited